# how to insert bind id again into the database

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

am binding id  to this anchor tag

`<a href="#@i.EmpID" >@i.Name</a>`

when i click on this name ,am showing a popup to insert one more name in database ,but i want to insert this bind id  and name into database how to do this

popup

```
<input type="text" name="MasterName">
@Html.ActionLink("Add", "addMaster", "Treeview")
```

**controller**(how can i get that id here and how to insert)

```
public ActionResult addMaster(string ID)
{
return View();
}
```

Comment: Your 2nd link needs to be `@Html.ActionLink("Add", "addMaster", "Treeview", new { id = i.EmpID }, null)`, but if you first link is in a loop, then you need to use javascript to build the href. But a link won't send the value of the textbox (and your method does not have a parameter for it anyway). You need a form for that

Comment: yes my first link in loop and in html helper, second link in view page am not able to get id there

Comment: You popup needs to be a form and you can to pass the ID value to it using javascript/jquery and assign it to a hidden input.

Comment: can you please give example, this is my jquery   $(function () {
        $('#masterClick').click(function () {
            $("#popupdiv").dialog({
                title: "Add New Master",
                width: 430,
                height: 250,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    Close: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    })